# I'm getting this error, I have installed requests using windows command prompt

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, python-requests

While installing requests in windows command prompt,I'm getting this error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\mukta\OneDrive\Desktop\MYweatherApp.py", line 2, in <module>
```

Import

```
import requests
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'requests'
```

Comment: Make sure that your `requests` installation path is in your `PYTHONPATH` in the environment variables.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the command `pip list` or `pip freeze` in the command prompt to check whether the `requests` module is installed or not.

You will get something like this :

```
C:\>pip list
Package     Version
----------- ---------
pip            20.2
requests       2.24.0
```

Maybe you are using a virtual environment, in that case, you need to install requests module in that virtual environment.

`pip install requests`

Comment: I'm using sublime text

Comment: Share your code and error screenshot in the question, maybe that will help

Answer (score 0):

Run this in your Command Prompt and then try to run

`pip install requests`

Then the module will get installed you are good to go!

:)